# What machine specs do you need in training of DETR?(End-to-End Object Detection with Transformers)

Tags: python, deep-learning, transformer-model

I am researching the machine specs needed for DETR training.
However, I only have a geforce 1660 super and I got an "out of memory" error. So, please let me know how much machine specs you have to use to complete the DETR training.
Please help me with my research.
DETR(https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr)

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting out of memory error because your GPU memory isn't sufficient to hold up the batch-size you input. Try running the code with minimum batch-size possible, see how much memory it consumes, increase the batch-size slightly, again check increase in memory consumption. This was you will be able to estimate how much GPU memory you require to run it with the actual batch-size.

I had the same issue, I switched to a machine with larger GPU memory (around 24 GB) and then everything worked fine!

Comment: Thank you.
What GPU is "around 24GB memory" referring to?

Comment: GPU "type" and "memory" are two different things. The machine I refered to here is an RTX 3010